# The frame of uitableview is not changing programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 `UITableView` in my `UIViewController`. one of them is in the right side of the screen till center of screen. The other is from center till left bound.

User can hide the right `UITableview` by pressing one a button on the navigation bar.

I use this code to make left `UITableview` full screen:

```
self.rightTableView.hidden= YES;
self.leftTable.frame= CGRectMake(0,
                                 self.dataTableView.frame.origin.y, 
                                 self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                 self.dataTableView.frame.size.height);
```

But it is not working.

I even put this code on the `viewdidload` and `viewDidAppear` methods but the frame not changing.

Comment: If your table is an IBOutlet it will be nil in viewDidLoad. Try putting your code in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? If you are, you will need to modify the constraints as opposed to the frame.

Comment: Yes tables are IBOutlet

Comment: Also I am using AutoLayout but I am not familiar with constraints

Comment: As mentioned, you must modify your constraints if you are going to use Autolayout. With Autolayout, programmatic changes to frames are effectively disregarded.

Comment: what is dataTableview? where you set it ?

Comment: first try with simple numbers like, 0,0, 320, 400, see if its work, then make it with dynamic numbers

Comment: you sure you connect between the tableViews and the IBOutlets?

Comment: @Jack Wu, you was righ, It was because I am using auto layout. When using auto layout you can not change the frame size. So It is better that make your comment and answer so that other viewer can use it better

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using autolayout, modifying the frame will have no effect.

Instead, you should modify the constraints.

You can do this by creating outlets for your constraints and connecting then in the interface builder.

Answer (score 14):

Try `self.leftTable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`, then call to frame resize at runtime is automatically translated into new constraints.

But,  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints will also cause new constraints to be added based on the view's autoresizingMask. So make sure other constraints are working properly.